# disabled.bind not changing after DOM load

Tags: html, aurelia

Below is the HTML snippet for a button that I would like to be disabled while no files, from a UI list of files, are selected:

```
<button id="downloadButton" disabled.bind="selectedFileCount() == 0" click.trigger="downloadFiles()" type="button">Download Selected</button>
```

The conditional function for whether the button is disabled or not:

```
selectedObjects = [];
selectedFileCount() {
    return this.selectedObjects.length;
}
```

When a file *is* selected, the following is triggered:

```
rowSelected($event) {
    this.selectedObjects.push($event.detail.row);
}
```

**I know** that rowSelected works properly as I can `console.log(selectedObjects.length)` and get the correct length. I know that `selectedFileCount()` works because I can return `boolean` values which are reflected in whether the button is disabled or not.

It appears that once `disabled.bind` is set on DOM load, it cannot be changed. Is this assumption correct? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Aurelia treats any function calls in a binding as being pure function calls. Since your `selectedFileCount` function doesn't take any parameters, this means that Aurelia assumes the output value of the function will never change. That is why your disabled binding never changes.

My recommendation for how to fix it is to simply put the check in the binding.

```
 <button id="downloadButton" disabled.bind="selectedObjects.length == 0" 
         click.trigger="downloadFiles()" type="button">
    Download Selected
 </button>
```